# XML query to API returns 'Premature end of file'

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to call an external site (API) which will return an XML response. I have tried several ways of doing this and end up with the same response: `Premature end of file`.  Unfortunately I am not able to get any positive feedback from the other site.  Below are the php commands I have tried and their results.  It woud appear to me that there is an issue on the other site.  I can copy the URL and paste into a browser and it works just fine.

```
$url = "https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/XMLServlet?request=<?xml version='1.0'?>";
$url .= "<REQUEST userid='p_panda1' password='practice00' facility='3003154010'>";
$url .= "<OBJECT name='clinicalreport' op='search_filedelivery'>";
$url .= "<receivingorganization>3003154010</receivingorganization>";
$url .= "<creation_datetime_from>09/01/2014</creation_datetime_from>"; 
$url .= "<creation_datetime_to>10/10/2014</creation_datetime_to>";
$url .= "<is_downloaded>n</is_downloaded></OBJECT></REQUEST>";


$myXML = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myXML);

$postdata = file_get_contents($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($postdata);


$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>";
echo $response,"<br>";
```

Output from the echo commands:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => Premature end of file.
)
Premature end of file.
Premature end of file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are creating is invalid.

You are creating a URL like:

```
https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/XMLServlet?request=<?xml version='1.0'?>...
```

Which would mean you have 2 questionmarks in it. Also for example < is not a valid url character as far as I know.

So you would have to url-encode that, like:

```
$request = '<?xml version='1.0'?>...etc...';
$url = "https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/XMLServlet?request=". urlencode($request);
```

Comment: This worked.  needed to change url_encode to urlencode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `urlencode` the parameter. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php for more info. After changing it to this, all 3 come back with a response.

```
$url = "https://cli-cert.emdeon.com/servlet/XMLServlet?request=";
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
$xml .= "<REQUEST userid='p_panda1' password='practice00' facility='3003154010'>";
$xml .= "<OBJECT name='clinicalreport' op='search_filedelivery'>";
$xml .= "<receivingorganization>3003154010</receivingorganization>";
$xml .= "<creation_datetime_from>09/01/2014</creation_datetime_from>"; 
$xml .= "<creation_datetime_to>10/10/2014</creation_datetime_to>";
$xml .= "<is_downloaded>n</is_downloaded></OBJECT></REQUEST>";

$url = $url . urlencode($xml);
```